# Substituting with awk variables

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

Basically, I need to make a copy and a substitution of `$1` (after `cat`ing a file) into `sample` variable in order to replace it in an address `/disk1/ngsep/"$sample"/"$1"_bowtie2_readpos.stats`. This is my attempt:

```
cat samples_long.10ids.txt | awk -v sample="$1" '{gsub(/_USD.*/,"",sample); print $sample,$1}'
```

which produces:

```
P2_142_USD16089440L_HJM27DSXX_L3 P2_142_USD16089440L_HJM27DSXX_L3
P2_144_USD16089441L_HJM27DSXX_L3 P2_144_USD16089441L_HJM27DSXX_L3
P2_145_USD16089442L_HJM27DSXX_L3 P2_145_USD16089442L_HJM27DSXX_L3
P2_168_USD16089450L_HJM27DSXX_L3 P2_168_USD16089450L_HJM27DSXX_L3
P2_171_USD16089451L_HJM27DSXX_L4 P2_171_USD16089451L_HJM27DSXX_L4
P2_172_USD16089452L_HJM27DSXX_L4 P2_172_USD16089452L_HJM27DSXX_L4
P2_188_USD16089456L_HJM27DSXX_L4 P2_188_USD16089456L_HJM27DSXX_L4
P2_262_USD16089477L_HJJNWDSXX_L2 P2_262_USD16089477L_HJJNWDSXX_L2
P2_270_USD16089479L_HJJNWDSXX_L2 P2_270_USD16089479L_HJJNWDSXX_L2
P2_271_USD16089480L_HJJNWDSXX_L4 P2_271_USD16089480L_HJJNWDSXX_L4
```

But I need:

```
P2_142 P2_142_USD16089440L_HJM27DSXX_L3
P2_144 P2_144_USD16089441L_HJM27DSXX_L3
P2_145 P2_145_USD16089442L_HJM27DSXX_L3
P2_168 P2_168_USD16089450L_HJM27DSXX_L3
P2_171 P2_171_USD16089451L_HJM27DSXX_L4
P2_172 P2_172_USD16089452L_HJM27DSXX_L4
P2_188 P2_188_USD16089456L_HJM27DSXX_L4
P2_262 P2_262_USD16089477L_HJJNWDSXX_L2
P2_270 P2_270_USD16089479L_HJJNWDSXX_L2
P2_271 P2_271_USD16089480L_HJJNWDSXX_L4
```

In order to use it in a longer pipeline:

```
cat samples_long.10ids.txt | 
cat `awk -v sample="$1" 'BEGIN {gsub(/_USD.*/,"",sample); print "/disk1/ngsep/"$sample"/"$1"_bowtie2_readpos.stats"}'` | 
awk '{if(NR<151) {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$3/$5*100} else {print $0}}' | 
less
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @cas answer I could to make it. I changed my longer pipeline:

```
tail -n +1 `awk '{sample=$1; gsub(/_USD.*/,"",sample); print "/disk1/ngsep/"sample"/"$1"_bowtie2_readpos.stats"}' samples_long.10ids.txt` | awk 'm=($1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) {print $0,$3/$5*100.0} !m {print $0}' | awk 'm=($1 == "==>") {save_location=$2} !m&&$1=="1",$1=="Bases" {print > save_location}'
```

Explanation:

First of all, I had several files, on different locations, of the form:

```
1 44270430 2888669 939293704 101672177
2 39504262 2535442 939293704 101672177
3 36179652 2298760 939293704 101672177
4 35187362 2216378 939293704 101672177
5 31718310 1957024 939293704 101672177
...
145 30614327 2148102 939293704 101672177
146 31053766 2211019 939293704 101672177
147 33769500 2475193 939293704 101672177
148 34799685 2574711 939293704 101672177
149 38192883 2761700 939293704 101672177
150 41098709 2974392 939293704 101672177

Alignments      939293704       101672177
Bases   140205023688    15190431468
```

And I wanted to make an operation, divide column 3 by column 5 and multiply by 100 and save it as a 6th column. Result:

```
1 44270430 2888669 939293704 101672177 2.84116
2 39504262 2535442 939293704 101672177 2.49374
3 36179652 2298760 939293704 101672177 2.26095
4 35187362 2216378 939293704 101672177 2.17993
5 31718310 1957024 939293704 101672177 1.92484
...
145 30614327 2148102 939293704 101672177 2.11277
146 31053766 2211019 939293704 101672177 2.17465
147 33769500 2475193 939293704 101672177 2.43448
148 34799685 2574711 939293704 101672177 2.53237
149 38192883 2761700 939293704 101672177 2.71628
150 41098709 2974392 939293704 101672177 2.92547

Alignments      939293704       101672177
Bases   140205023688    15190431468
```

Therefore, let me explain the longer instruction:

```
`awk '{sample=$1; gsub(/_USD.*/,"",sample); print "/disk1/ngsep/"sample"/"$1"_bowtie2_readpos.stats"}' samples_long.10ids.txt` |
```

This is why I needed to make a substitution, in order to get all addresses of the files written in `samples_long.10ids.txt`. Each file is saved in a directory named, e.g. `P2_142`. Result:

```
/disk1/ngsep/P2_142/P2_142_USD16089440L_HJM27DSXX_L3_bowtie2_readpos.stats
/disk1/ngsep/P2_144/P2_144_USD16089441L_HJM27DSXX_L3_bowtie2_readpos.stats
/disk1/ngsep/P2_145/P2_145_USD16089442L_HJM27DSXX_L3_bowtie2_readpos.stats
/disk1/ngsep/P2_168/P2_168_USD16089450L_HJM27DSXX_L3_bowtie2_readpos.stats
/disk1/ngsep/P2_171/P2_171_USD16089451L_HJM27DSXX_L4_bowtie2_readpos.stats
...
```

`tail -n +1`: I used it because I needed to read all files (in stdout) that are aimed by the printed addresses of `awk` and added they respective location. Result:

```
==> /disk1/ngsep/P2_142/P2_142_USD16089440L_HJM27DSXX_L3_bowtie2_readpos.stats <==
1 37000568 2614993 747883433 76303046
2 33228316 2330791 747883433 76303046
...
149 33852828 2660530 747883433 76303046
150 36161756 2836045 747883433 76303046

Alignments      747883433       76303046
Bases   111613795461    11392665612

==> /disk1/ngsep/P2_144/P2_144_USD16089441L_HJM27DSXX_L3_bowtie2_readpos.stats <==
1 40000373 2754292 838333186 82982133
2 35955786 2451917 838333186 82982133
...
```

`awk 'm=($1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) {print $0,$3/$5*100.0} !m {print $0}' |`
Here I did my operation by printing only when $1 matched a number and when not, just printed the whole line without operating. Result:

```
==> /disk1/ngsep/P2_142/P2_142_USD16089440L_HJM27DSXX_L3_bowtie2_readpos.stats <==
1 37000568 2614993 747883433 76303046 3.42711
2 33228316 2330791 747883433 76303046 3.05465
...
149 33852828 2660530 747883433 76303046 3.48679
150 36161756 2836045 747883433 76303046 3.71682

Alignments      747883433       76303046
Bases   111613795461    11392665612

==> /disk1/ngsep/P2_144/P2_144_USD16089441L_HJM27DSXX_L3_bowtie2_readpos.stats <==
1 40000373 2754292 838333186 82982133 3.31914
2 35955786 2451917 838333186 82982133 2.95475
...
```

`awk 'm=($1 == "==>") {save_location=$2} !m&&$1=="1",$1=="Bases" {print > save_location}'`
After making the operation I needed to save each corresponding file to the specific directory. Thus, when one use `tail -n +1`, it attaches file location, between `==>` and `<==`, to the output then I saved this location in the variable `save_location` by assigning to `$2` if `$1=="==>"`. If not, I saved the rest between patterns `1` and `Bases` to the address that was pointed by `save_location`. The file corresponding to the `P2_142` sample as example:

```
1 37000568 2614993 747883433 76303046 3.42711
2 33228316 2330791 747883433 76303046 3.05465
3 30544208 2130666 747883433 76303046 2.79237
4 29727794 2059047 747883433 76303046 2.69851
5 26873913 1825829 747883433 76303046 2.39287
...
145 27262253 2093226 747883433 76303046 2.74331
146 27992017 2188217 747883433 76303046 2.8678
147 30385435 2433407 747883433 76303046 3.18913
148 31218703 2514902 747883433 76303046 3.29594
149 33852828 2660530 747883433 76303046 3.48679
150 36161756 2836045 747883433 76303046 3.71682

Alignments      747883433       76303046
Bases   111613795461    11392665612
```

Comment: Sorry but your commands don't really make sense. Can you explain what you thought would happen? You are trying to `cat` a string, what are you expecting? And why are you piping cat to cat with `cat file | cat`? And what is `$1` supposed to be in your command?

Comment: `$1`: P2_142_USD16089440L_HJM27DSXX_L3
`sample`: P2_142
I'm trying to automate an operation because I have 95 files thus I use cat for the file `samples_long.10ids.txt` (just 10 ids of the rest 95). Then I use the other cat to print the content of a file located in `/disk1/ngsep/P2_142/P2_142_USD16089440L_HJM27DSXX_L3_bowtie2_readpos.stats` which later will be operated with awk to print his columns and add a sixth column by an arithmetic operation ($3/$5*100)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information. Comments are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. If you [edit], you can use the [format] to make sure everything is clear. I'm afraid most of the commands you're using won't work, and I can't help you get the right commands if you don't explain what you expect the commands to do. For example, your `awk` won't do anything since you have everything in the `BEGIN{}` block which is run _before_ reading the first line.

Comment: @terdon thank you for your time and consideration, I will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done with sed.

```
$ sed -E -e 's/^((.*)_USD.*)/\2 \1/' input.txt 
P2_142 P2_142_USD16089440L_HJM27DSXX_L3
P2_144 P2_144_USD16089441L_HJM27DSXX_L3
P2_145 P2_145_USD16089442L_HJM27DSXX_L3
P2_168 P2_168_USD16089450L_HJM27DSXX_L3
P2_171 P2_171_USD16089451L_HJM27DSXX_L4
P2_172 P2_172_USD16089452L_HJM27DSXX_L4
P2_188 P2_188_USD16089456L_HJM27DSXX_L4
P2_262 P2_262_USD16089477L_HJJNWDSXX_L2
P2_270 P2_270_USD16089479L_HJJNWDSXX_L2
P2_271 P2_271_USD16089480L_HJJNWDSXX_L4
```

This sed script makes use of two capture groups i.e. regexp patterns surrounded by `(` and `)`.  The first being the entire input line, and the second being the first part of the line before the `_USD`.  It replaces each input line with the 2nd capture group (`\2`), a space, and then the 1st capture group (`\1`).

Or with `awk`:

```
awk -F'_' -e '{print $1 "_" $2 " " $0}' input.txt
```

This sets the input field separator to `_`, then (for each line of input) it prints the first two fields with an underscore between them, a space, and then the entire input line.

---

There are several problems with your command:

```
cat samples_long.10ids.txt | \
  awk -v sample="$1" '{gsub(/_USD.*/,"",sample); print $sample,$1}'
```

1. you don't need cat to pipe a file into awk.  awk can read filenames given as arguments on its command line.
2. You are setting an awk variable `sample` to "$1".  I presume you mean the first field in awk, not the first argument to some (un-shown) shell script wrapper.  That's not going to work.  awk's `$1` doesn't exist in the shell.  It only exists when awk reads a line of input data.
3. You haven't told awk what to use for a field separator, so it defaults to white space (spaces and tabs).  With your sample input, there are no space characters, so $1 is the entire input line (which is referred to as `$0`).
4. you are printing "$sample".   This is telling awk that you want to print the field number contained in variable `sample`.

   `sample`  contains a string, so evaluates to `0` in that context - `print $sample` is equivalent to `printing $0`. so your code there is effectively `print $0 $1`.   Which is effectively `print $0 $0` - you are printing the entire line twice.
5. if you want to print the contents `sample` itself (and not field number that `sample` evaluates to), then just `print sample`.
6. Points 4 & 5 probably needs more explanation or, at least, an easier example to understand.

   Every time awk reads an input line, it automatically sets a variable called `NF` to the number of fields in that line.

   If you want to print the number of fields, you just print `NF`.   If you want to print the field whose field number is equal to NF, you print `$NF` (This will print the last field of the input line).

   You can also do arithmetic and other operations on NF (it's an integer).  e.g. `print $(NF-1)` will print the second last field.

   Back to your code: you printed `$sample`. In an integer context, `sample` had the value `0`, so you printed `$0`, which is the entire input line.
7. With all of the above in mind, this would work:

   ```
   awk '{sample=$1; gsub(/_USD.*/,"",sample); print sample,$1}' samples_long.10ids.txt
   ```

   But it's overly complicated for a simple task like this.  awk can split the input into fields separated by underscores, so it's easier to just do that.

   ```
   awk -F'_' -e '{print $1 "_" $2 " " $0}' samples_long.10ids.txt
   ```

Comment: Thank you a lot for taking the time and explain me!

Answer (score 0):

Rookie `awk` mistake...

`awk` takes the file as an argument:

> gawk [ POSIX or GNU style options ] [ -- ] program-text **file** ...

Comment: Only if you don't want to read from standard input (like from a pipe). I don't see how this would change very much for the user.

Comment: @Kusalananda The user is `cat`ing the file and piping it to `awk` (incorrectly I might add by putting another `cat` in there). If they simply use `awk` they won't have to deal with their piping, and in the case of reading from the file (which is their use case) it simplifies things.

Comment: Yes, that is all well and good. Put that in your answer, because your answer is currently not actually showing how to solve the user's problem.

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm torn on that, it addresses *why* they're having an issue rather than writing up the solution. The leaning is more valuable in my opinion, but if you feel otherwise I'd invite you to write an answer as well.